# Update configuration file to use cache

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, server, ngrok

Im having an error analysing the page speed of a site saying "Leverage browser caching". It seems that is necessary to change the configuration in the apache or nginx  config file. Im just using valet ngrok to test in a url like "https://....ngrok.io". Do you know what is the configuration file that is necessary to edit and what is necessary to edit?

Comment: Why bother for a dev environment?